# C program to remove multiple blank spaces

Tags: c, logic

I have a problem with the following program. It works, but even if the logic seems correct, if I insert two characters separated by m blank spaces, it gives back the same two characters separated by m/2 blank spaces.

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
int main(void)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  int c;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  int n = 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  printf("Insert one or more strings. Possible double blank spaces will be removed.\n\n");                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  while((c = getchar()) != EOF)                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    if(c != ' ')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
      if(n != 0)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
      {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        putchar(c);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        n = 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
      }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
      else                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
      {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        putchar(c);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
      }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    else                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
      if(n != 0)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
      {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        n = 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
      }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
      else                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
      {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        putchar(c);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        n++;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
      }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  return 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
}
```

Anyone sees the problem?

Comment: You do `n = 0;` whenever `n != 0` is true. So you only skip the first space after a space.

Comment: You should only set `n = 0` when you read a non-space, not when you read a space.

Comment: I rolled back your edit. The solution should be posted below as an Answer, not put in the question.

Comment: @Joe, Tip use a more meaningful name than `n`.  It will help you and others uncover the bug.

Comment: @Joe Simplify: `if (c != ' ') { if (n != 0) { putchar(c);  n = 0; } else { putchar(c); } }` same as `if (c != ' ') { putchar(c); n = 0; }`.

Comment: `int main(void) { int c; while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) { if (c == ' ') { putchar(' '); while ((c = getchar()) == ' ') continue; if (c == EOF) break; } putchar(c); } return 0; }` works quite nicely.  I used `continue` because it makes things clearer in the flattened code in a comment on SO; I'd omit it in normal code, with the semicolon on a line on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in several comments, the code *resets* the flag variable `n`, effectively suppressing only *the second of any pair* of sequential SPs.

---

Instead of adding more flags and conditions, it is often better to go for a walk and re-think your approach.

With less code, the following works well:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) {
    puts( "Insert one or more strings. Consecutive blank spaces will be reduced to single spaces.\n" );

    for( int c, n = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF; n = c == ' ' )
        if( !n || c != ' ' )
            putchar( c );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I post my own answer.

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
int main(void)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  int c;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  int n = 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  printf("Insert one or more strings. Possible double blank spaces will be removed.\n\n");                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  while((c = getchar()) != EOF)                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    if(c != ' ' && n == 0)                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
      {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        putchar(c);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
      }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    else if(c != ' ' && n > 0)                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
      {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        putchar(c);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        n = 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
      }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    else if(c == ' ' && n == 0)                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
      putchar(c);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
      n++;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    else                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
      n++;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  printf("\n");                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  return 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).